# How to make libreoffice headless conversion act differently on file loading error

Tags: shell-script, libreoffice

I use a script via my file manager context menu to convert various document formats (e.g. *.DOC) to ODT format like this:

```
for filename in "${@}"; do
    if [[ -f "${filename%.*}.odt" ]]
    then
        newfile="${filename%.*}_$(stat "$filename" | grep "Modify" | awk -F " " '{print $2}').odt"
        mv "${filename%.*}.odt" "${filename%.*}.tmp"
        libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt "$filename"
        mv "${filename%.*}.odt" "$newfile"
        touch "$newfile" -r "$filename"
        mv "${filename%.*}.odt.tmp" "${filename%.*}.odt"
        rm "$filename"
    else
        libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt "$filename"
        touch "${filename%.*}.odt" -r "$filename"
        rm "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately, this results in removing a file without conversion if it is password-protected.

Terminal output in such case is "Error: source file could not be loaded"

I guess (and hope) it would take just a little bit  more shell scripting skills to improve the very basic script above so that the input file is not removed but simply skipped (perhaps with an error message or log file as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal world `libreoffice` will let you know with an exit code that the conversion did not take place. But [it seems that's not the case](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/does-libreoffice-throw-any-error-code-message-while-converting-password-protected-file-to-pdf/74319/4).

So you have at least two alternatives, one is parsing the standard error and remove the file only if the error message is not there (you check the exit code from `grep` and hope for the pipe not be broken before that):

```
for filename in "${@}"; do
    libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt "$filename" 2>&1 | grep "source file could not be loaded" || rm "$filename"
done
```

Another possibility is to check if the odt file has been created before removing the source (an incomplete conversion might trigger the removal though). Something like this:

```
for filename in "${@}"; do
    libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt "$filename"
    test -f ${filename%.*}.odt && rm "$filename"
done
```

Comment: Maybe consider `test "${filename%.*}.odt" -nt "$filename"` in case the conversion failed, but there happened to be a pre-existing .odt file of the same name?

Comment: The first one works perfectly, thanks! I think this could be a very handy script for many who might need to convert batches of MS Office files, and in that case ideally it would be very nice also to display failed filename(s) at the end of the operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, LibreOffice doesn't have any terminal output at all for password-protected spreadsheets (e.g. xls), in which case the second option (or the alternative suggested by @steeldriver ) should be used. If there is already a file with same name, I guess the script should better check this first, and use another name for the output file.